# Setting up SSL on Apache2 - Not switching after apache2 restart

Tags: server, apache2, ssl

So, I've looked through literally dozens of tutorials online.

I have apache 2.4.7 on a ubuntu 14.04 digital ocean droplet.

I can reach my site fine with http, but want to switch it to https.

I get certificates from letsencrypt and am trying to get them to go.

I have setup my default-ssl.conf with the Virtual host as described in many of the tutorials.

I use

`a2ensite default-ssl.conf`

to enable it, and

```
service apache2 reload
```

and

```
service apache2 restart
```

to reload and restart apache2.  But to no avail.

http site still opens fine, but https won't resolve.

I have an apache2.conf file in /etc/apache2 that is setup for traffic on port 80 (http).

Is there something I need to do in that file?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so just had to make a new VirtualHost entry for 443 in the /etc/apache2/apache2.conf file....instead of those other ssl files.

Not sure why this was never in any of the tutorials I found out there. But it is fixed.